# How to make scroll two tables at the same time but scroll should be visible only for body div

Tags: css

I have the following scenario with dynamic content loading for some reason, I would like scroll together both header div and body div while scrolling body div.

I have tried but no luck. Is there anyways to do through CSS.

```
<div class="Main">
   <div class="header">
      <table></table>
  </div>
   <div class="body" style="overflow-x: auto">
      <table></table>
   </div>
<div>
```

Comment: add `overflow` to the main div then ?

Comment: show your css code

Comment: why can't you give overflow property to class="Main"?

Comment: I'm using clusterize js for lazy loading.  so when we use overflow to main div, lazy loading will not work that means next set up content will not load.

Comment: Is there any twick using css to make equal scollable for upper div.

Comment: Add a child div to "Main" div and add overflow property to the child div?

Comment: I want to show the scrollbar only for body content. If I give parent div, scrollbar will be visible from header

Answer (score 0):

So you want a scroll for the table inside body div and when user scrolls in it you want to scroll head div as well.

If I'm correct till now then it's not possible with CSS because scrolling happens only for the selected element. Now you can make both scrolls together if you make their parent as scrollable which is div with class **main**.

If you still want the same behavior like how you expecting then you have to use JS to achieve this. If you are having trouble implementing in JS do let know. Cheers :)

Comment: I know through Js is possible but looking for CSS tricks if any